# How could i change the state of a radiobutton in a radiogroup?

Tags: android, kotlin

How could I change the state of a radio button in a radio group?
I get the value Male or Female from Firebase(stored before out of the radio group) and fill again the Layout. Now I have to convert the Male information to the radio button of the radio group

```
var rg = radioGruppe                              
rg!!.setOnCheckedChangeListener(RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener 
{ 
group, checkedId ->
   Log.i("test", "The ID is: ${group.checkedRadioButtonId}")
})
```

The ID is: 2131230874
But what have I to do now?

Comment: What do you mean "change state"? Do you have a radio group that contains 1 "male" radio button and 1 "female" radio button, and you're just trying to have one of these 2 selected based on what comes from Firebase? Or do you want to perform an action when any of those radio buttons is clicked by the user?

Answer (score 0):

found it by myself:

```
rbMale = mView?.findViewById((R.id.rb_male))
rbFemale = mView?.findViewById((R.id.rb_female))
if(Gender == "Woman") {
   radioGruppe!!.check(rbFemale!!.id)
} else {
  radioGruppe!!.check(rbMale!!.id)
}
```